# Sporadic long response time for OpenShift gear

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, openshift

I have two Flask apps in OpenShift. Each one in a free small gear. Each one uses an own PostgreSQL cartridge. The code is quite simple: REST apps that do a query in the DB and return a JSON. The DB is almost empty and, in this test phase, they are accessed only by me and a response time recorder.

Most of the time, for both apps, the response time is ~300ms, what is great.
But sometimes the response takes much longer: 4s, 7s, 12s or even 15s. The same request taking 50X more time to return.

If these slow response requests were spaced 24h/48h I would say it's some kind of OpenShift idle policy. But they aren't. It's more like any request has a 5% chance of being a slow one, even if they are spaced only a few seconds. And if the requests are spaced a few minutes the "chance of being slow" raises for more than 50%.

Any ideas?
Thanks for the attention!

Comment: I have noticed this also.  I always attributed it to being on a free gear.  You get what you pay for.  :) It would  be interesting to know if that was true or not.